# Python socket slow to connect for SMTP after multiple successful connections

Tags: python, sockets, email, amazon-web-services, smtp

I have a script that is emailing out PDFs to our clients and am having an issue where when I start the script, it sends up to three PDFs and then it starts to take 1-2 minutes for each subsequent email to send out. I can halt the script and start over in a few minutes, allowing the same result where three go out and the rest are molasses.

I've narrowed it down to a server problem, with near certainty, but I don't know what it could be. I have two servers, one from an old AWS account, and that one can send emails quickly over and over again. The new AWS account server can do three. When I interrupt the program, I know that it is stuck connecting because this is the trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test_reports.py", line 202, in <module>
    send_email(advertiser_email, sales_email, emailSubject, emailBody, fname, sendEmail=True)
  File "./test_reports.py", line 158, in send_email
    smtp = smtplib.SMTP('email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com')
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/smtplib.py", line 251, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/smtplib.py", line 335, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/smtplib.py", line 306, in _get_socket
    self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/socket.py", line 702, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

If I run strace on the python process while it is trying to send, I get this:

```
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(25), sin_addr=inet_addr("54.243.225.221")}, 16)
```

I now have a test script where it only sends an email, and I notice I can run that three times as well before it takes forever to send. I am thinking it is some sort of rate limit on the server, but I'm not sure where to look now.

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being the repeated establishment of the connection. I established the connection near my global variables and just passed it in to send_email() instead of establishing each time. I had tried this earlier and it didn't work, but I think it was because it was inside of a loop.